# Как узнать массив координат границ Mesh Collider

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, mesh

### Вопрос такой нужно узнать массив координат, что бы взял рандомную точку и допустим спавнить объект на границе коллайдера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но нужен массив что бы спавнить допустим несколько объектов поверх метеорита как показано на след. картинке**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

должно быть то что ты хочешь

```
Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
```

Comment: https://radikal.ru/video/eALLnsU2d9y, У меня  mesh при старте почему то сам указал позицию и работает исключительно в ней, как можно решить данную проблему

Comment: у меня нету доступа к радикалу. А по тексту ничего не понял

Comment: https://youtu.be/A9WTlQzeLN4 в описании скинул скрипт

Comment: Я хочу полностью покрыть объектами границы коллайдера, как волосы на голове

Comment: я вижу оно делает необходимую форму но больше необходимых размеров. Вероятнее всего виноват скейл.

Comment: массив векторов который я беру с объекта - mesh.vertices, почему то всегда равен одному значению

Comment: что значит одному значению? Один элемент массива?

Comment: Неа, массив большой на 514 элементов. На видео показано как я двигаю объект после запускаю сцену и вот этот масив каждый элемент всегда равен одному значение, только к каждому элементу то есть меняю координаты сферы а mesh.vertices остается прежним. Каждый его элемент всегда имеет свои координаты вне зависимости от того где расположен объект и его mesh filter.

Comment: Это потому, что эти значения - локальная система координат, а тебе нужна глобальная. https://answers.unity.com/questions/1304791/getting-the-world-position-of-mesh-vertices.html

Comment: Спасибо большое прям то что мне надо, вы ангел спаситель.В ответ скину скрипт может кому то пригодиться.

Comment: Отметь ответ как верный. галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 0):

```
public Mesh mesh;

    public GameObject Prefab;
    public List<Transform> Artefactq;
    public List<Vector3> PosForArtefact;
    void Start()
    {
        mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;

        for (int i = 0; i < mesh.vertices.Length; i += 15)
        {
            Vector3 world_v = transform.localToWorldMatrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(mesh.vertices[i]);
            PosForArtefact.Add(world_v);

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < PosForArtefact.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Artefactq.Count != PosForArtefact.Count)
            {
                Transform Artef = Instantiate(Prefab).transform;
                Artefactq.Add(Artef);
                Artef.transform.position = PosForArtefact[i];
                Artef.SetParent(transform);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]